# JAXB generate nillable = "true" from java

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-nil, jaxbelement

it this a bug?

I need `nillable = "true"` in my xsd schema. The only way to generate such an element from my java code is to use `@XmlElement(nillable = true)`, right? But in this case, I will not be able to take advantage of this definition, I will not be able to check if the element is set to `nil`. The method `isNil()` is in the `JAXBElement` wrapper class.

So, what are my options here - I want to generate `nillable = "true"` in my xsd schema AND be able to check if it is set from my java code.

Comment: Isn't `xs:nil=true` and `null` the same? So if your element is set to nil in xml your field will be null in java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need nillable = "true" in my xsd schema. The only way to generate
>   such an element from my java code is to use @XmlElement(nillable =
>   true), right?

Yes.

> But in this case, I will not be able to take advantage of this
>   definition, I will not be able to check if the element is set to nil.
>   The method isNil() is in the JAXBElement wrapper class.

You can do `getFoo() == null` to determine if it was null.  If you are trying to determine if the null corresponds to an absent element or `xsi:nil="true"` then you will have to do more.  A set won't be done for absent nodes so you can put logic in your setter to track if a set to null was done because of an element with `xsi:nil="true`.

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
public String getFooString() {
    return fooString;
}

public void setFooString(String foo) {
    this.fooString = foo;
    this.setFoo = true;
}
```

If you don't want to have this extra logic (which doesn't help for marshalling anyways you need to leverage `JAXBElement`.

```
@XmlElementRef(name="fooJAXBElement")
public JAXBElement<String> getFooJAXBElement() {
    return fooJAXBElement;
}

public void setFooJAXBElement(JAXBElement<String> fooJAXBElement) {
    this.fooJAXBElement = fooJAXBElement;
}
```

---

### Java Model

**Root**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"fooString", "barString", "fooJAXBElement", "barJAXBElement"})
public class Root {

    private String fooString;
    private String barString;
    private JAXBElement<String> fooJAXBElement;
    private JAXBElement<String> barJAXBElement;

    private boolean setFoo;
    private boolean setBar;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    public String getFooString() {
        return fooString;
    }

    public void setFooString(String foo) {
        this.fooString = foo;
        this.setFoo = true;
    }

    public boolean isSetFooString() {
        return setFoo;
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    public String getBarString() {
        return barString;
    }

    public void setBarString(String bar) {
        this.barString = bar;
        this.setBar = true;
    }

    public boolean isSetBarString() {
        return setBar;
    }

    @XmlElementRef(name="fooJAXBElement")
    public JAXBElement<String> getFooJAXBElement() {
        return fooJAXBElement;
    }

    public void setFooJAXBElement(JAXBElement<String> fooJAXBElement) {
        this.fooJAXBElement = fooJAXBElement;
    }

    @XmlElementRef(name="barJAXBElement")
    public JAXBElement<String> getBarJAXBElement() {
        return barJAXBElement;
    }

    public void setBarJAXBElement(JAXBElement<String> barJAXBElement) {
        this.barJAXBElement = barJAXBElement;
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="fooJAXBElement")
    public JAXBElement<String> createFooJAXBElement(String string) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("fooJAXBElement"), String.class, string);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name="barJAXBElement")
    public JAXBElement<String> createBarJAXBElement(String string) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("barJAXBElement"), String.class, string);
    }

}
```

### Demo

Below is a full example to demonstrate the concepts discussed above.

**input.xml**

This document contains 2 elements explicitly marked with `xsi:nil="true"` and 2 other mapped elements that are absent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <barString xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <barJAXBElement xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</root>
```

**Demo**

This demo code will read in the above XML and check whether the properties have been set as a result of the unmarshal.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, ObjectFactory.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum20076018/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println("Was fooString set?  " + root.isSetFooString());
        System.out.println("Was barString set?  " + root.isSetBarString());
        System.out.println("Was fooJAXBElement set?  " + (root.getFooJAXBElement() != null));
        System.out.println("Was barJAXBElement set?  " + (root.getBarJAXBElement() != null));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  We see that all the is set checks are correct, but that the output only fully matches the input for the `JAXBElement` properties.

```
Was fooString set?  false
Was barString set?  true
Was fooJAXBElement set?  false
Was barJAXBElement set?  true
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <fooString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <barString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <barJAXBElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks! When I put the `@XmlElement(nillable = true)` on the getter and check if the setter has been called to set the field to `null` it works. There is just one small problem: if I have an element of `type="xs:dateTime"` then I have a `private Date dateFromXml` field. If the date in the xml is not properly set, like `<date>blabla</date>` then the setter `setDateFromXml(final Date dateFromXml)` will be called to set the field to `null` - the same behaviour as when the xml has `xsi:nil="true"`. Is there a solution to this problem?